# remove url from jira application on tomcat

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat, apache2, jira

My goal is to remove the port number from the jira application url.
Now it is accessible via:

```
http://192.168.199.151:8080/jira
```

I want to access it via:

```
http://192.168.199.151/jira
```

Here are my configs and environment info:

**OS** :

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
xenial
```

**apachectl -V** :

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-05-05T16:32:00
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:52
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

**sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf**:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

ServerName 192.168.199.151
```

**~/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080"
                   maxThreads="150"
                   minSpareThreads="25"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   enableLookups="false"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
                   redirectPort="8443"
                   acceptCount="100"
                   disableUploadTimeout="true"
                   bindOnInit="false"
                   proxyName="192.168.199.151"
                   proxyPort="80"/>
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
                <Context path="/jira" docBase="${catalina.home}/atlassian-jira" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                    <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"
                              factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>
                    <Manager pathname=""/>
                    <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
                </Context>
            </Host>
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                   pattern="%a %{jira.request.id}r %{jira.request.username}r %t &quot;%m %U%q %H&quot; %s %b %D &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot; &quot;%{jira.request.assession.id}r&quot;"/>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

and finally:
**/etc/apache2/sites-available.jira.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 192.168.199.151
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia Off
        <Proxy *>
          Require all granted
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass /jira http://localhost:8080/jira
        ProxyPassReverse /jira http://localhost:8080/jira 
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*everything is running on my local virtual ubuntu server on vmware.*
**http://192.168.199.151** opens up my apache2 server welcome page.

### update:

Opening this `http://192.168.199.151/jira`, gives the following error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /jira was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.18
>   (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.199.151 Port 80

### update 2:

I updated this line in jira.conf file to point to the application directory (i don't know if it is needed or not):

```
DocumentRoot /home/thomas/atlassian/jira
```

and added location:

```
<Location /jira>
Require all granted
</Location
```

and run the a2ensite command:

```
sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/jira.conf
```

and i get this error:

> ERROR: Site /etc/apache2/sites-available/jira does not exist!

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with apache - but looking at your config does loading  http://192.168.199.151/jira open anything?

Comment: @PeterReid i updated my question regarding your point.

Comment: The `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` directive might be interfering?

Comment: @PeterReid i commented it out, but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     ProxyPass /jira http://localhost:8080/jira
> ```
>
> http://192.168.199.151 opens up my apache2 server welcome page.

You asked Apache to proxy /jira, not /, so this config is not
yet being tested. The config looks reasonable otherwise.

Edit for 404 followup:

> /etc/apache2/sites-available.jira.conf

Is this site enabled with a2enable? Is it shown by apachectl -S?

Comment: sorry, i forgot tell you that i have also tested it, i get an error. see the updated question for the error

Comment: please check the updated question regarding your suggestion.